# simple question about define a path

Tags: php

im very sorry to ask a very simple question, its seems im not understanding define path properly

as you can see

```
i put this at D:\Project Storage\wnmp\www\folder\scriptfolder 
example D:\Project Storage\wnmp\www\folder
define('SAMPLE1', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/..'));
example D:\Project Storage\wnmp\www\somefolder
define('SAMPLE2', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../somefolder/'));
how  do we put like D:\Project Storage\wnmp\www\folder\scriptfolder/ ? ( add '/') ?
define('SAMPE3', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/')); it seems its not working.
```

thanks for looking in

Adam Ramadhan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`realpath()` will never add a trailing slash because it's not a part of the path.

Either add it outside the realpath statement

```
realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/'
```

or when you use it

```
$path = ROOT."/xyz.php";
```

Comment: oh shit. i forgot this one, thanks pekka, really unthinkable. how could i miss that ? thanks again. you save me time.